# Adding color and a position to a created button

Tags: java, swing, button, colors, position

thanks in advance for the help.
I have this code to create a button:

```
frame1.getContentPane().add(new DragButton("Z"));
```

And i added a random position:

```
frame1.getContentPane().add(new DragButton("Z")).setLocation((int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 600) + 1),(int) Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1));
```

But now i want to add color to the button. I know i can use the .setBackground(Color.GREEN) option, but in doing so after or before using the .setLocation option, it gives me a "void cannot be deferenced" error and im stuck in this part. I already saw several post here but they either focus on the position part or the color part, not both. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reference to the button...

```
 DragButton zButton = new DragButton("Z");
```

Modify its properties...

```
zButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

Add the button...

```
frame1.getContentPane().add(zButton);
```

Many of the methods in Java don't support method chaining, sometimes it would be nice, sometimes not, seek out the designers of the original AWT API and ask them why...

Comment: Thanks, its working perfectly, but i think you meant to do this:
    `frame1.getContentPane().add(zButton);`
Sorry if the code doesnt shows has code, following the question, can i do this if i create, say zButton,xButton and so on ? I mean, dont they interfere with each other ?

Comment: Yay, at least its only twelve colors =) thanks a lot.

Comment: You could create method that deals with the basic reation of the buttons, passing the parameters you need to seed it..